# LevelHelper and Box2D Collions: How to get "tag"?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, collision, levelhelper

I have successfully made a very simple LevelHelper/Box2D/Cocos2D project.
I am now trying to register a collision as described in the documentation [here](http://www.levelhelper.org/app/documentation/docs/COCOS2D_Box2d_collision.htm).

I used the example code as follows:

```
[lh registerBeginOrEndColisionCallbackBetweenTagA:COIN
                                          andTagB:MARIO
                                       idListener:self
                                      selListener:@selector(beginEndCollisionBetweenMarioAndCoin:)];
```

My Question is this: how do I get the tag? Am I correct in setting it in LevelHelper in the "General Properties" pane? (below)

[image: LevelHelper Tag is set to CHARACTER_TAG?]

In LevelHelper's Custom Properties window the "Tag Value" for "CHARACTER_TAG" is 1, but if I try and put this into the above code instead of "MARIO" XCode gets upset because it "cannot initialize a parameter of type 'enum LevelHelper_TAG' with an rvalue of type 'int' " (fair enough).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out!

After setting the tag to `CHARACTER_TAG` in LevelHelper, I needed to regenerate my code with File\Generate Code\Cocos2D with Box2D. Then I could simply type CHARACTER_TAG in place of MARIO as seen in my question!

I hope this helps someone!